# Make does not follow symbolic links to find files

Tags: makefile, symlink

When I extract files from a tar ball to create a list of files make does not follow symbolic links and keeps extracting the same tar ball for each file specified in the list. Forinstance I have created 2 tar balls with the following commands in linux:

design1 is a directory that holds a link to another directory with c design files

```
% mkdir design1
% mkdir c_files
% cd c_files/
% touch a.c b.c c.c d.c e.c f.c
% cd ../design1/
% ln -s ../c_files/ .
% cd ..
% gtar zcvf design1.tgz design1/
```

design2 is the same as design1 except that c_files is a directory and not a link

```
% mkdir design2
% 
% cp -rp c_files design2
% gtar zcvf design2.tgz design2/
```

Now there are 2 zipped tarfiles design1.tgz and design2.tgz and design1 and design2 directories are removed

```
% \rm -rf design1 design2
```

Here's my Makefile:
----------------Begin Makefile -------------------

```
DESIGN_EXTRACT_DIR := .
DESIGN_TOP1 := c_proj1
FILE_LIST1 := $(strip $(DESIGN_TOP1)).f


DESIGN_TAR_FILE1 := design1.tgz
DESIGN_RELEASE_DIR1 := $(DESIGN_EXTRACT_DIR)/design1

DESIGN_FILES1 =\
$(DESIGN_RELEASE_DIR1)/c_files/a.c   \
$(DESIGN_RELEASE_DIR1)/c_files/b.c   \
$(DESIGN_RELEASE_DIR1)/c_files/c.c   \
$(DESIGN_RELEASE_DIR1)/c_files/d.c   \
$(DESIGN_RELEASE_DIR1)/c_files/e.c   \
$(DESIGN_RELEASE_DIR1)/c_files/f.c   \


IP_EXTRACT1: $(DESIGN_FILES1) 

$(DESIGN_FILES1): $(DESIGN_TAR_FILE1)   
    gtar zxvfmhC $(DESIGN_TAR_FILE1) $(DESIGN_EXTRACT_DIR) 

$(FILE_LIST1): $(DESIGN_FILES1) 
    @( rm -f $(FILE_LIST1) )
    @( touch $(FILE_LIST1) )
    @$(foreach file, $(DESIGN_FILES1), `echo $(file) >> $(FILE_LIST1)`)


FL1:    $(FILE_LIST1)

DESIGN_TOP2 := c_proj2
FILE_LIST2 := $(strip $(DESIGN_TOP2)).f


DESIGN_TAR_FILE2 := design2.tgz
DESIGN_RELEASE_DIR2 := $(DESIGN_EXTRACT_DIR)/design2

DESIGN_FILES2 =\
$(DESIGN_RELEASE_DIR2)/c_files/a.c   \
$(DESIGN_RELEASE_DIR2)/c_files/b.c   \
$(DESIGN_RELEASE_DIR2)/c_files/c.c   \
$(DESIGN_RELEASE_DIR2)/c_files/d.c   \
$(DESIGN_RELEASE_DIR2)/c_files/e.c   \
$(DESIGN_RELEASE_DIR2)/c_files/f.c   \


IP_EXTRACT2: $(DESIGN_FILES2) 

$(DESIGN_FILES2): $(DESIGN_TAR_FILE2)   
    gtar zxvfmhC $(DESIGN_TAR_FILE2) $(DESIGN_EXTRACT_DIR) 

$(FILE_LIST2): $(DESIGN_FILES2) 
    @( rm -f $(FILE_LIST2) )
    @( touch $(FILE_LIST2) )
    @$(foreach file, $(DESIGN_FILES2), `echo $(file) >> $(FILE_LIST2)`)


FL2:    $(FILE_LIST2)

clean: 
    @( rm -rf $(FILE_LIST1)* $(FILE_LIST2)* )
```

----------------End Makefile----------------------

Now when I run make to create a file list I use the commands make FL1 and make FL2. In the case of FL1 make iterates of gtar as many times as I have files but doesn't do so with FL2. The only difference here is FL1 operates on a link called c_files in design1 while FL2 iterates over c_files as a directory.
Here's what I see:

```
% make FL1
gtar zxvfmhC design1.tgz . 
design1/
design1/c_files
gtar zxvfmhC design1.tgz . 
design1/
design1/c_files
gtar zxvfmhC design1.tgz . 
design1/
design1/c_files
gtar zxvfmhC design1.tgz . 
design1/
design1/c_files
gtar zxvfmhC design1.tgz . 
design1/
design1/c_files
gtar zxvfmhC design1.tgz . 
design1/
design1/c_files


%make FL2
%
```

Issue1:
FL1 creates c_proj1.f and FL2 creates c_proj2.f but FL2 doesnt iterate like FL1 and I am not sure how to prevent this iteration especially since I could have large tar ball with hundreds of files.

Issue2:
When DESIGN_FILES1 is a long list because of the number of files then I get the following error because the variable is too long:
make: execvp: /bin/sh: Argument list too long

Is there a way to check the size of the variable and maybe write to a file and process the variable a bit at a time so DESIGN_FILES will not be too long for each iteration. Or is there a better way to do this.

Thanks

Niel

Answer (score 0):

For me it works the same (iterates once) whether there is a symlink or not. But from the contents it seems that you are only interested in generating file list, so file existence is not really required. If you omit dependency, you may generate file list without even extracting the files.

For the actual file list write the oversized command line error comes from the fact, that the generated command is a single line with multiple subshell calls, which might be too long for the command line indeed:

```
$ make FL1 --trace
...
Makefile:24: update target 'c_proj1.f' due to: design1/c_files/a.c design1/c_files/b.c design1/c_files/c.c design1/c_files/d.c design1/c_files/e.c design1/c_files/f.c
( rm -f c_proj1.f )
( touch c_proj1.f )
`echo ./design1/c_files/a.c >> c_proj1.f`  `echo ./design1/c_files/b.c >> c_proj1.f`  `echo ./design1/c_files/c.c >> c_proj1.f`  `echo ./design1/c_files/d.c >> c_proj1.f`  `echo ./design1/c_files/e.c >> c_proj1.f`  `echo ./design1/c_files/f.c >> c_proj1.f`
```

This part can be resolved with a `$(file)` function (if you happen to use GNU make 4.1+):

```
.PHONY: $(FILE_LIST1)
$(FILE_LIST1):
        $(file >$@)
        $(foreach file,$(DESIGN_FILES1),$(file >>$@,$(file)))
```

If an older make is used, this could be done with regular commands, you just need to generate a newline character after each `echo` to make it work as a separate command. The only tricky part is that it has to be done as a specially crafted variable:

```
# Note double empty lines below
define newline


endef

.PHONY: $(FILE_LIST2)
$(FILE_LIST2):
        rm -f $@
        $(foreach file,$(DESIGN_FILES2),echo $(file) >> $@$(newline))
```

Result is now generated in separate shell calls, which should avoid command length limit:

```
$ make FL2
rm -f c_proj2.f
echo ./design2/c_files/a.c >> c_proj2.f
echo ./design2/c_files/b.c >> c_proj2.f
echo ./design2/c_files/c.c >> c_proj2.f
echo ./design2/c_files/d.c >> c_proj2.f
echo ./design2/c_files/e.c >> c_proj2.f
echo ./design2/c_files/f.c >> c_proj2.f
```

**EDIT:**

I was able to reproduce your multiple iteration of extraction. Your `tgz` file does not actually contain the files you claim to extract, so the files are not there when the first one is trying to be extracted and the extraction continues for the next file (which is also absent). This is also suggested by `tar` output, which says:

```
design1/
design1/c_files
```

instead of:

```
design1/
design1/c_files
design1/c_files/a.c
design1/c_files/b.c
design1/c_files/c.c
design1/c_files/d.c
design1/c_files/e.c
design1/c_files/f.c
```

Your `tgz` only contains a directory symlink and it only extracts a symlink. If the target files do not exist in the target location, it will attempt to re-extract for every file.

**EDIT2:**

When actual files are not included in the `tgz` file, but are available through a symlink, there is a chance that they are older than the `tgz` file itself. In such situation `make` checks the file timestamp through a symlink and discovers that it needs to be remade - but the file is not actually remade (since it's not included in the `tgz`). This check is done for every single file, so for every file the archive is extracted:

```
$ make FL1 -d
...
     Finished prerequisites of target file 'design1/c_files/a.c'.
     Prerequisite 'design1.tgz' is newer than target 'design1/c_files/a.c'.
    Must remake target 'design1/c_files/a.c'.
tar zxvfmhC design1.tgz .
Putting child 0x7fffe11ae730 (design1/c_files/a.c) PID 6286 on the chain.
Live child 0x7fffe11ae730 (design1/c_files/a.c) PID 6286
design1/
design1/c_files
Reaping winning child 0x7fffe11ae730 PID 6286
Removing child 0x7fffe11ae730 PID 6286 from chain.
    Successfully remade target file 'design1/c_files/a.c'.
    Considering target file 'design1/c_files/b.c'.
      Pruning file 'design1.tgz'.
     Finished prerequisites of target file 'design1/c_files/b.c'.
     Prerequisite 'design1.tgz' is newer than target 'design1/c_files/b.c'.
    Must remake target 'design1/c_files/b.c'.
tar zxvfmhC design1.tgz .
...
```

In general extracting archive in this way is not reliable anyway (image running in parallel with `-j`), so it would be better to use a [group target rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Multiple-Targets) to explicitly point out that this rule generates all the files at the same time:

```
$(DESIGN_FILES1) &: $(DESIGN_TAR_FILE1)
        tar zxvfmhC $(DESIGN_TAR_FILE1) $(DESIGN_EXTRACT_DIR)
```

This however is a new feature introduced in GNU make 4.3, so to make it work with previous versions, we could use a phony target that is only used for synchronization, e.g.:

```
$(DESIGN_FILES1): extract-$(DESIGN_TAR_FILE1)

.PHONY: extract-$(DESIGN_TAR_FILE1)
extract-$(DESIGN_TAR_FILE1):
        tar zxvfmhC $(DESIGN_TAR_FILE1) $(DESIGN_EXTRACT_DIR)
```

Output:

```
$ make FL1
tar zxvfmhC design1.tgz .
design1/
design1/c_files
```

Note that the archive is now extracted only once.

Comment: Thanks for the response. In this snippet I am generating a file list but I use the file list to do a compile so I will need to execute tar and extract the files and the files must exit or the compile will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I followed your advice and changed the dependency and it resolves the tar issue. The file function in make resolves the length of the variable but I have 2 undesired effect due to it. I have added one more thing to the mix here and I cannot explain the behavior:

On linux:

```
  % mkdir -p design3/c_files
  % cd design3/c_files
  % touch x.c y.c z.c
  % cd ../..
  % ls ./design3/c_files/*.c >  design3/c_proj3.f
```

Here's what I have done to the Makefile:

```
DIR_LIST := design3

IP_EXTRACT1: $(DESIGN_TAR_FILE1)   
    gtar zxvfmC $(DESIGN_TAR_FILE1) $(DESIGN_EXTRACT_DIR) 

$(DESIGN_FILES1): 
    $(MAKE) IP_EXTRACT1

$(FILE_LIST1):  $(DESIGN_FILES1) 
    $(file > $(FILE_LIST1))
    @$(if $(strip $(DIR_LIST)), cat $(foreach dir, $(DIR_LIST), $(wildcard $(dir)/*.f)) >> $(FILE_LIST1))
    @$(foreach file,$(DESIGN_FILES1),$(file >>$(FILE_LIST1),$(file)))
```

This resolves the tar issue but now I have added DIR_LIST and I want to add the list of files in each directory to the file list. It does the right thing but it has a couple of undesired effect:

1) I expect the content of design3/c_proj3.f at the top but it appears in the end.

```
%make FL1
%more c_proj1.f
./design1/c_files/a.c
./design1/c_files/b.c
./design1/c_files/c.c
./design1/c_files/d.c
./design1/c_files/e.c
./design1/c_files/f.c
./design3/c_files/x.c
./design3/c_files/y.c
./design3/c_files/z.c
```

I expected x, y, z at the top as there is order dependence but its at the bottom. Also, if I do make FL1 --dry-run after removing c_proj1.f the files a through f gets into it but not x,y,z because that is from a cat shell command. I would prefer no files get created. Is there a way to resolve this?. This is a partial solution so I am not sure if this needs to go back into the question.